# .NETの「AppendPrivatePathは旧形式です」への改善方法

Tags: c#, .net

VS2017 v15.8.7、.net framework 4.7.2にて、
アプリの配置においてサブフォルダ内にdllをまとめたいと思っております。
以下のコードを利用すると

```
//サブフォルダ"bin"に配置したdllを読み込む
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AppendPrivatePath(
    Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"bin")
);
```

> 'AppDomain.AppendPrivatePath(string)'は旧形式です (... Please investigate the use of AppDomainSetup.PrivateBinPath instead. ...)

と、表示されます。

このままでもアプリケーションは問題なく動作するのですが、旧形式ではないコードにしたいと考えております。
現行のコードを教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 検索するとヒットする日本語の記事はこれあたりでしょうか。[検索パスを追加した新しいAppDomain](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/qnzm/20090208/1234109756) [AppDomain と動的読み込み](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/dd296853.aspx) ご参考に。

Comment: @kunif こちらも参考にしてみます。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Why is AppDomain.AppendPrivatePath Obsolete?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2009/05/14/why-is-appdomain-appendprivatepath-obsolete/)で説明されていますが、`AppDomain.AppendPrivatePath`は安全ではありません。
`AppDomain`が作成されプログラムが既に開始されてからのPath変更となるからです。解決策も提示されていてアプリケーション構成ファイルの[`<probing>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element)を使います。具体的には`app.config`に

```xml
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="bin" />
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

と記述することで、プログラム開始前に設定できます。